# Finding a value in one table which doesn't exist in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find instances where a student has a module with an XXX suffix in a table called SMO but no non-XXX variant as long as the non-XXX variant exists on a table called MAV.

I.e.

```
SPR_CODE - MOD_CODE
 1. 1234 - AA101XXX
 2. 5678 - AA101XXX
 3. 5678 - AA101
```

Should return:

```
SPR_CODE - MOD_CODE
 1. 1234 - AA101XXX
```

The primary keys that really matter (I think) are the student code (spr_code), the academic year (ayr_code), and the module code (mod_code)

At the moment I can't seem to work out how to do it, but I could just be overthinking it. I tried starting in SMO and going from there, but I can't get it to work:

```
select
sm1.spr_code
,sm1.mod_code
,sm2.mod_code

from
cam_smo sm1
left join cam_smo sm2 on ((substring(sm1.mod_code,1,charindex('XXX',sm1.mod_code)-1) = sm2.mod_code) and (sm1.spr_code = sm2.spr_code))

where
sm1.mod_code like '%XXX'
and sm1.ayr_code = '2019/0'
```

I haven't thrown in the MAV table yet because I'm just trying to find instances of students having an XXX suffixed module while not having a non-XXX suffixed module, then I'm going to make sure the non-XXX module exists in the MAV table down the line. I haven't written SQL in a while and I'm incredibly tired so I could just be being stupid, but I thought left join would show all instances of sm1.spr_code/sm1.mod_code existing and then return nulls on the column for sm2.mod_code but it isn't...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `exists` and `not exists` to me:

```
select smo.*
from smo
where smo.mod_code like '%XXX' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from smo smo2
                  where smo2.spr_code = smo.spr_code and
                        smo2.mod_code + 'XXX' = smo.mod_code
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from mav
              where mav.mod_code + 'XXX' = smo.mod_code
             );
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'm mostly certain we're on a SQL based database (it's now becoming increasingly apparent that there are gaps in my training...) so I've replaced the || with + and it brings back the relevant values which is great. Terrifyingly, this has brought back 700 instances which is really not good as there should be 0. After checking, it looks like another team seems to just keep relic modules active.

Either way, this works excellently. Thank yo so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To just get the first part - instances of students having XXX stuffed module while not having a non-xxx stuffed module, you can also do:

```
select sm1.spr_code,sm1.mode_code
from cam_smo sm1 left outer join cam_smo sm2
on sm1.spr_code = sm2.spr_code
and sm1.mode_code <> sm2.mode_code
where sm2.mode_code is null and sm1.mode_code like '%XXX'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I probably should have been clearer in my information, apologies. The students will have other modules as well, they just won't have the non-XXX variant of the XXX module. This finds people who only have an XXX module which is still great and finds some orphan records, but it doesn't find the people I'm specifically looking for. 

But thanks for the response! I'm going to check the exist/not-exist response as well, but it's not something I've used before.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the above query only finds students having XXX module with no non-XXX module, which I thought was what you required in the first part. For the second part you stated  "...then I'm going to make sure the non-XXX module exists in the MAV table down the line.". Hence if I understand it correctly, you want to check if non-XXX variant exists in the MAV table, for the spr_code retrieved in the first part. Thus you can use the first query to get the spr_codes having only XXX variant and check if they exist in the MAV table with non-XXX variant

Comment: Ah, sorry, the aim was to find instances where a student has an XXX variant of a non-XXX module but doesn't have the non-XXX module, so it wouldn't be for people who purely have an XXX module as all students will have a variety of other modules. It's just some modules are supplemented with an extra module to aid timetabling. So if someone has an XXX variant module they should always have the normal one as well, and this was to help identify instances where a student has been taken off the base module but not the supplementary module. 

And now the word module doesn't look like a real word.